# Question in munkres topology page 160

Tags: general-topology

In page 160 munkres says that if there exists a path $f:[a,b]\to X$ from $x$ to $y$ whose domain is the interval $[a,b]$, then there is also a path $g$ from $x$ to $y$ having the close interval $[c,d]$ as its domain and this follows from the fact that any two closed intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ are homeomorphic.

Could anyone to explain or to prove this please?

Some extra clarification:
1) $X$ is an arbitary topological space
2) Definition: A equivalance relation on the space $X$ by the defining $xRy$ is there is a path in $X$ from $x$ to $y$.The equivalence classes are called path components.

Comment: @sigmabe Sorry, my wrong!Some lines previous munkres has the definition: A equivalance relation on the space X by the defining xRy is there is a path in X from x to y.The equivalence classes are called path components.

Comment: X is an arbitary space

Answer (score 1):

Look at the map
$$g: [c,d]\to [a,b], x\mapsto \frac{(x-c)(b-a)}{d-c}+a$$
It is an example of the mentioned homeomorphism. Soo if $f: [a,b]\to X$ is a path form $x$ to $y$ then
$$f\circ g : [c,d]\to X$$
is also a path from $x$ to $y$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had this problem exactly. I couldn 't find function g.